# Unable to get the Android Location API to work

Tags: android, google-maps, location

My goal is to get the current location of someone and place a marker on that spot on Google Maps. It seems that the location is returning null. When I was debugging, it seemed like the methods for the OnConnection callbacks were not working either. The device is connected and well because I can use the mMap.setMyLocationEnabled which allows for finding location, but does not give data for the location. I am running on a HTC One M8.

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private LatLng mLastLocationLatLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Test"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10), 500, null);
        }
    });

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    //Gets last location of user - is usually the current
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLastLocationLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLastLocationLatLng, 15));
    }
    else {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(0,0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: Is there any error? Post stacktrace.

Comment: There is no error because I think that the OnConnected callbacks are not being called in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not called [`googleApiClient.connect();`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()) anywhere. That's why none of the connection-related callbacks are being triggered.